# single select drop down list have filter using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
 <td valign="middle">
     <select id="b1selection" 
             size="5"
             class="singleselect" 
             style="width: 370px">
         <asp:Repeater ID="rptDescription" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <option value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                         id='Description<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
                     <%# Eval("Title") %>
                 </option>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
     </select>
     <input id="b1" name="b1" runat="server" 
            type="text" 
            class="text-input small-input" 
            style="display: none;"
            value="" />
 </td>
```

I want to have dropdown which bind from the database. It should have filter functionality such as if i write in textbox letter "S" then all item from "S" in drop down it will filter. so please help me out.

I had tried with jquery with the help of this link

> http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#filter

but above link is for multiple select but i want single select.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Autocomplete textbox of Ajaxtoolkit. and modified the css to give it a feel like dropdown box. Try using this [post](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/09/ajax-autocompleteextender-textbox-width.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the jquery autocomplete plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/